# Livy Server on Amazon EMR hangs on Connecting to ResourceManager

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, emr

I'm trying to deploy a Livy Server on Amazon EMR. First I built the Livy master branch

```
mvn clean package -Pscala-2.11 -Pspark-2.0
```

Then, I uploaded it to the EMR cluster master. I set the following configurations:

**livy-env.sh**

```
SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
```

**livy.conf**

```
livy.spark.master = yarn
livy.spark.deployMode = cluster
```

When I start Livy, it hangs indefinitely while connecting to YARN Resource manager (XX.XX.XXX.XX is the IP address)

```
16/10/28 17:56:23 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /XX.XX.XXX.XX:8032
```

However when I netcat the port 8032, it connects successfully

```
nc -zv XX.XX.XXX.XX 8032
Connection to XX.XX.XXX.XX 8032 port [tcp/pro-ed] succeeded!
```

I think I'm probably missing some step. Anyone has any idea of what this step might be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made the following changes to the config files after unzipping the livy-server-0.2.0.zip file

**livy-env.sh**

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/spark-client
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/bin/
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=$SPARK_HOME/conf
export LIVY_LOG_DIR=/jobserver-livy/logs
export LIVY_PID_DIR=/jobserver-livy
export LIVY_MAX_LOG_FILES=10
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/bin
```

**livy.conf**

```
livy.rsc.rpc.server.address=<Loop Back address>
```

Add 'spark.master yarn-cluster' in the 'spark-defaults.conf' file which is under spark conf folder.

Please let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: Hey Balakrishna, thanks for the answer! The Livy server is starting now! However, all sessions are starting **dead**. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: @matheusr, can you please enable debug logging

Comment: It works! However, I needed to build the master branch of Livy. This because Livy 0.2 does not support Spark 2 or Scala 2.11. The above configurations it's all that is needed to make it work.

Comment: Good to hear. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following in your log4j.properties, Please post the log file.

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, NotConsole

log4j.appender.NotConsole=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.NotConsole.File=/<LIVY SERVER INSTALL PATH>/logs/livy.log

log4j.appender.NotConsole.maxFileSize=20MB

log4j.appender.NotConsole.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.NotConsole.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
```

Comment: @matheusr, Spark library is not loading. Can you please copy the spark library to <livy install folder>/jars folder.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the github repo , it looks like master branch is under-development and there is a separate release branch for 0.2 version. The straighforward way (which worked for me) to install livy is to follow the  steps in the quickstart page: http://livy.io/quickstart.html

## Download Livy Server distribution

```
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/beta/livy/livy-server-0.2.0.zip
```

## unzip

```
unzip livy-server-0.2.0.zip
```

## start

```
$ cd livy-server-0.2.0
$ ./bin/livy-server
16/11/07 20:32:51 INFO LivyServer: Using spark-submit version 2.0.0
16/11/07 20:32:51 WARN RequestLogHandler: !RequestLog
16/11/07 20:32:51 INFO WebServer: Starting server on http://ip-xx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal:8998
```

Comment: Could you give more details about how you configured Livy please?

Comment: The bounty is expiring, I will start another one as soon as it expires.